# What happens if Nuget and Paket versions of the same package have different versions in my solution?

Tags: f#, nuget, paket

I installed `Paket for Visual Studio` from

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteffenForkmann.PaketforVisualStudio.

Then I created a new project (actually a solution) and checked immediately that a `NuGet` package called `System.ValueTuple` already was installed under `NuGet`. (I did not install this package). The package version was `v4.4.0` but I could see that version `v4.5.0` was already available.

After a bit of tampering I arrived at a condition where `NuGet` still had version `v4.4.0` of `System.ValueTuple` while `Paket` was supposedly using `v4.5.0`. The details of how I did this are tedious and are at the bottom of this post.

Do I have to worry that `NuGet` and `Paket` are referencing different versions of the `System.ValueTuple` package?

Should I update that package in `NuGet` to version `v4.5.0`?

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Details of how I ended up with two different versions in `NuGet` and `Paket`:

I did `Tools\Paket Dependencies Manager\Update All Packages`, hoping to update the package. However, nothing happened. `v4.4.0` was still the version installed in `NuGet`.

At this point my solution did not have a `.paket` folder, a `paket.dependencies` file or a `paket.lock` file.

So I went to the `Solution Explorer` and chose `References\Add Package` and added the `Deedle` package. I also added the `System.Data` package that is required by `Deedle`.

I checked again and the version of `System.ValueTuple` did not change in `NuGet`.

Once again I did `Tools\Paket Dependencies Manager\Update All Packages`but `v4.4.0` was still the version installed in `NuGet`.

So I did `References\Add Package` and added `System.ValueTuple` to `Paket`. The package appeared in `paket.dependencies` but it still had `v4.4.0` in `NuGet`. I opened the file `paket.lock` with an editor and searched for `ValueTuple`. I could see the following: `System.ValueTuple (4.5)` on line 482 and no other instances on other lines.

Comment: I don't think you should mix Paket and Nuget in the same solution, although I do it temporarily now and then just to fix this problem. I have noticed that updating System.ValueTuple via NuGet doesn't always work, so what I do is that I manually insert a reference to it in the project file, with the updated version number. Just copy the line that references FSharp.Core, and modify the name. Set both to 4.5.0. Another possibility is to convert the project to use Paket, and then add System.ValueTuple using Paket.

Comment: @BentTranberg - I created a new solution and updated System.ValueTuple to v4.5.0. It still showed as a NuGet installed package. Then I copied paket.bootstrapper.exe to the root directory and ran it. A paket.exe file was created. On a command prompt I entered paket.exe convert-from-nuget. Then I looked again and there were no NuGet packages installed. 1) Did Paket uninstall System.ValueTuple (as a Nuget package)? (It still appears in the System.Explorer). 2) Is this what you mean by converting the project to use Paket? 3) Have I stopped mixing Paket and Nuget in the same solution?

Comment: I know too little to tell whether there's something wrong with that you're doing, but what I've done is update the version numbers of FSharp.Core and System.ValueTuple to 4.5.0 in the project file's PackageReference entries, any which way possible - using NuGet update when it worked, or manually if not. In both cases, only the project file was modified. Later when introducing Paket, those two entries still remain in the project file, so I assume they're ok.

Comment: The "NuGet" node in the Solution Explorer doesn't mean you're not using Paket. I think your project uses Paket if it has a line in the project file that that says <Import Project="..\.paket\Paket.Restore.targets" />